# unreachable statement after while

Tags: java, while-loop

I was just modifying code and I got error in the following code:

```
    int x=1;
    System.out.println("x "+x);
    while (true)    {
        x++;
    }
    System.out.println ("x "+x);
```

The error is in the last line. Can I know what the error(error: unreachable statement) means?

Also how can I modify code such that value of x increased inside while loop doesn't change the global value and also what modification will change global value?

Comment: When is `while(true)` supposed to end? Please read your own code more carefully. And what is the purpose of that loop anyway? To "freeze" the program?

Comment: @Tom Yeah I missed that part.

Comment: You should first learn the basics of programming logic, before jumping here to ask a question. What's more, that kind of question already exists on SO. For instance, take a look at the one on my comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I know what the error(error: unreachable statement) means?

This means that the written code is of no use as it will not be executed because the previous line's (code) statements will never come out or return from the method, this happens in the following scenarios:

**(1) Infinite loops or iterations (like `while(true)` or `for(;;)` )**

```
public R method() {
  while(true) { //infinite loop
    //some code
  }
  //from here the below code will never get executed
}
```

**This is what your case is and your code `x++;` runs forever and never comes out of the `while` loop.**

**(2) When you throw an exception after that the code statements will not get executed as shown below:**

```
public R method() {
  //some code
  throw new MyException(" Exception is ... ");
  //from here code is unreachable
}
```

**(3) Using explicit `return` statement**

```
public R method() {
      //some code
      return r;
      //from here code is unreachable
    }
```

Comment: yes, also remember that there are other cases where you will get unreachable statement as explained above

Answer (score 1):

the `while` loop

```
while(true)
```

will run forever (the condition is never `false`) and so the code after it will never be executed.

To solve this, put the printing into the loop:

```
while (true){
    x++;
    System.out.println ("x "+x);
}
```